# R - Why verbose = FALSE don't work with certain models?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, r-caret

I want to omit the messages given by the following model

```
library(caret)
library(pamr)

data(iris)

fit_pam <- train(Species ~ .,
                 data = iris,
                 method = "pam")
```

output:

`12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293011111111111111111111111111`

But using the option `verbose = FALSE` the model does not work.

```
fit_pam <- train(Species ~ .,
                 data = iris,
                 method = "pam",
                 verbose = FALSE)
```

and gives the following warnings, like the option is not recognized:

`unused argument (verbose = FALSE)`

I don't have this problems with other models.

However, if this could be omitted with the options in Rmarkdown it would also work for me.
But `{r message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}` did not work when I knit.

**Answer in the comments:**

Comment: `verbose` is not an argument for `train(.)`, which will then try to forward it to `pamr`. I cannot find reference to `verbose` as an argument in [its docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pamr/pamr.pdf) either. I don't use `caret` or `pamr` regularly, so I might be missing something, but what indicates that `verbose=` is supposed to do anything?

Comment: The option verbose = FALSE works for example with this "gbm" model, and helps to omit unwanted outputs. It is passed through the `...` options of the `train()` function.

Comment: Yes. The [`gbm(.)`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf) does have `verbose=` as an argument. *Not all functions do.* The `caret::train` function calls many other packages' functions, and the arguments for each vary. Just because it is found in one does not mean it is found in all. Go to the `pamr` docs link I provided in my first comment, and search for `verbose`; I didn't find it when I searched. Since `train(..., method="pam")` just forwards `...`-arguments to `pamr`, and `pamr` does not use `verbose=`, one cannot ***project*** verbose functionality where it does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, this really is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

What about using `sink()`

```r
library(caret)
library(pamr)

data(iris)
sink(tempfile())
fit_pam <- train(Species ~ .,
                 data = iris,
                 method = "pam")
sink()
```

Or, in RMarkdown, you could use `results='hide'`